# How to use dash or hyphen to join a string array in Powershell

Tags: string, powershell, automation, escaping

I wrote code like this:

```
$count = 0
$path = "C:\Videos\"
$oldvids = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Include *.* -Recurse
foreach ($oldvid in $oldvids) {
    $curpath = $oldvid.DirectoryName
    $name = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($oldvid)
    $names = $name.Split(" - ")
    $names[0] = ""
    $metadata_title = $names -join "-"
    $ext = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($oldvid)

    if ($name.StartsWith("new_") -eq $false)
    {
        $newvid = $curpath + "/new_" + $name + ".mp4"
        if ([System.IO.File]::Exists($newvid) -eq $false)
        {
            $count++
            
            Write-Output $metadata_title
            
        }
    }
}
```

But this code causes a file name like this:

> Chapter 1 - New Video

to become:

> Chapter 1---New Video

How can I make sure a single - is actually only one? Do I have to escape it?

The idea is to eliminate first part of the file names, so from:

```
01 - Chapter 1 - Video 1
```

to:

```
Chapter 1 - Video 1
```

So I wanted to split using " - " and then join everything back without the first element in the split array.

Comment: I'm actually unsure what you want to achieve with this code. You split the file name in the middle and actually eliminate the first part. If the name did not start with `new_` you add it and also add the extension `.mp4` regardless if the original extension was something else. ??? What's the goal?

Comment: While its not completely clear what you're doing here for the reasons @Olaf mentions, I suspect one of your issues is related to you using the split Method `$name.Split(" - ")` as it matches as a char array, you likely want to use the split Operator  `$name -split " - "` which will match as a string.

Comment: Also, why don't you use the properies of the FileInfo object PowerShell provides? `[System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($oldvid)` -> `$oldvid.BaseName` and `[System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($oldvid)` --> `$oldvid.Extension`. Please show us some examples of filenames and what you would like to get as `$metadata_title`. BTW.  because you're not specifying switch `-File` to the Get-ChildItem cmdlet, you will also get directories back..

Comment: Added extra info just now.

Comment: @Theo, I didn't know I could do those. These were what I found online where the quality of information is not consistent. The last point: you mean instead of -Path, use -File? I will make those changes.

Comment: @Theo, I didn't know I could do those. These were what I found online where the quality of information is not consistent. The last point: you mean instead of -Path, use -File? I will make those changes.

Comment: I'd do it with a `-replace` like this: `-replace '(?<=^)\d+\s+-\s+'`

Comment: No, you leave `-Path`, but ADD the `-File` parameter. Please have a look at [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem)

Comment: Thanks for the example, but.. What happened to the `new_` you prefix your filename with in your code?  This is what I meant with adding `-File`: `$oldvids = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter *.* -File -Recurse` (I' also changed -Include to -Filter because that is very much faster but can only be used when you have just one single filename pattern)

Comment: @Olaf, will that only remove the numbers in the beginning including the " - "?

Comment: @Theo. I am using ffmpeg to change metadata so I need to generate a new file temporarily. That's why I am using new_, then manually delete the old files and then rename the new ones.

Comment: @JoanVenge Why don't you try it? ... with some test files ...

Comment: $str = [string]'01 - Chapter 1 - Video 1'; $output = $str.Substring($str.Indexof('-') + 1).Trim();  write-host $output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your example and your explanation of changing metadata with ffmpeg on each file, I guess this is what you need:

```powershell
$count = 0
$path = 'C:\Videos'
# get a list of old video files (these do not start with 'new_')
$oldvids = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter *.mp4 -File -Recurse |
           Where-Object { $_.Name -notmatch '^new_' }

foreach ($oldvid in $oldvids) {
    # if the file is called 'C:\Videos\01 - Chapter 1 - Video 1.mp4'
    $tempName = $oldvid.Name -replace '^\d+\s*-\s*(.+)', 'new_$1'  # --> new_Chapter 1 - Video 1.mp4
    # or do
    # $tempName = 'new_' + ($oldvid.Name -split '-', 2)[-1].Trim() # --> new_Chapter 1 - Video 1.mp4
    # or
    # $tempName = $oldvid.Name -replace '^\d+\s*-\s*', 'new_'      # --> new_Chapter 1 - Video 1.mp4

    # combine the current file path with the temporary name
    $outputFile = Join-Path -Path $oldvid.DirectoryName -ChildPath $tempName

    #######################################################################
    # next do your ffmpeg command to change metadata
    # for input you use $oldvid.FullName and for output you use $outputFile
    Write-Host "Updated file $($oldvid.Name) as $tempName"
    #######################################################################

    # when done with ffmpeg, delete the original (or for safety move it to somewhere else)
    Write-Host "Deleting file '$($oldvid.Name)'"
    $oldvid | Remove-Item -WhatIf 

    # and rename the updated file by removing the 'new_' part from its name
    $newName = ($tempName -replace '^new_').Trim()
    Write-Host "Renaming updated file to '$newName'"
    $tempName | Rename-Item -NewName $newName

    # all done, proceed with the next file
    $count++
}
```

Note: I have added switch `-WhatIf` to the Remove-Item line.  This is a safety measure that will only display what file ***would*** be deleted without actually deleting it.
If you are sure the correct file should be deleted, then remove that `-WhatIf` switch so the original file gets destroyed after maipulating it with ffmpeg.

---

As per your comment, to send items to the **Recycle bin** instead of destroying them like `Remove-Item` does, here's two ways of achieving that:

**Method 1: Use COM**

```
function RemoveTo-RecycleBin {
   [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [Alias('FullName')]
        [string[]]$Path
    )
    begin {
        $shell = New-Object -ComObject 'Shell.Application'
        $Recycler = $Shell.NameSpace(0xa)
    }
    process {
        foreach ($item in $Path) {
            [void]$Recycler.MoveHere($item)
        }
    }
    end {
        # clean-up the used COM objects
        $null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Recycler)
        $null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($shell)
        $null = [System.GC]::Collect()
        $null = [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
    }
}

# usage example, remove all files from the D:\Test directory
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -Filter '*.*' -File | RemoveTo-RecycleBin

# usage example, remove all files and subdirectories from the D:\Test directory
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' | RemoveTo-RecycleBin
```

**Method 2: Use the Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly**

```
function RemoveTo-RecycleBin {
   [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [Alias('FullName')]
        [string[]]$Path,

        [switch]$ShowConfirmationDialog
    )
    begin {
        Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
        $showUI = if ($ShowConfirmationDialog) { 'AllDialogs' } else { 'OnlyErrorDialogs' }
    }
    process {
        foreach ($item in $Path) {
        Write-Host $item
            # detect if this is a file or a directory
            if ((Get-Item -Path $item) -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]) {
                # first parameter:  the absolute full path
                # second parameter: one of Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.UIOption values:      OnlyErrorDialogs  or AllDialogs
                # third parameter:  one of Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.RecycleOption values: DeletePermanently or SendToRecycleBin
                [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem]::DeleteDirectory($item, $showUI, 'SendToRecycleBin')
            }
            else {
                # first parameter:  the absolute full path and file name
                # second parameter: one of Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.UIOption values:      OnlyErrorDialogs  or AllDialogs
                # third parameter:  one of Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.RecycleOption values: DeletePermanently or SendToRecycleBin
                [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem]::DeleteFile($item,$showUI, 'SendToRecycleBin')
            }
        }
    }
}

# usage example, remove all files from the D:\Test directory
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -Filter '*.*' -File | RemoveTo-RecycleBin

# usage example, remove all files and subdirectories from the D:\Test directory
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' | RemoveTo-RecycleBin
```

Just choose any of the above functions, put it on top of your script and then change line

```
$oldvid | Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

into

```
$oldvid | RemoveTo-RecycleBin
```

Comment: thx it works. one thing i didnt have was using .FullName to send the old vid file path to ffmpeg. Otherwise it works well. Also is there a way to delete the files where they go to recycle bin? i didnt try remove-item.

Comment: @JoanVenge Please see my edit where I posted two different functions to delete files and folders to the recycle bin instead of destroying them